# Routing to L2TP/IPSec VPN (strongswan, xl2tpd). Can ping server inside VPN, cannot ssh (SSH is not ESP payload)

Tags: routing, ipsec, l2tp, strongswan, xl2tpd

I created a L2TP/IPSec tunnel and I am struggling with routing, I cannot SSH to a machine in the remote network. My local system is Debian buster (current testing).

Here is my local networkg config; interface `ppp0` is the tunnel interface.

```
#ip a
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:aa:14:27:3a:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.13/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 71692sec preferred_lft 71692sec
    inet6 fe80::feaa:14ff:fe27:3abf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1410 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
    inet 172.16.100.15 peer 10.10.10.10/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I need to connect to `172.16.100.116` server, inside the VPN network. I only need this one addres, other communication should go through my home router.

This is the routing table after creating the tunnel:

```
# ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0 proto static metric 100 
10.10.10.10 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.100.15 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.13 metric 100
```

I added:

```
ip r a 172.16.100.116 via 10.10.10.10
```

I can `ping` it, cannot `ssh` (no route). I run wireshark and saw that even `TSP SYN` is without the answer (but `ICMP` is getting back).

I also discovered that under Windows SSH works in this tunnel, but it is carried as ESP payload, but under Linux I get TCP SYN when trying to SSH.

I tried about dozen of routes and nothing worked for me.
Could someone help?

K.

Comment: Have you tried running `tcpdump -pni ppp0` while attempting a connection?

Comment: Another question: What does the routing table look like after you added the extra routing entry?